# Sprite Kit with Swift "use of unresolved identifier 'size'" in sample code

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have looked through the suggested answers on this site as well as searched for my own. I've tried appending identifiers in the code to items that I think might fit (though I'm new to Swift and Sprite Kit to a degree) and I can't figure this out.  The code is below.

```
func addMonster() {

// Create Sprite

let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")

// Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis

let actualY = random(min: monster.size.height/2, max: size.height - monster.size.height/2)

// Position the mosnter slightly off-screen along the right edge and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above

monster.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + monster.size.width/2, y: actualY)

// Add the mosnter to the scene

addChild(monster)

// Determine speed of the monster

let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(4.0))

// Create the actions

let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -monster.size.width/2, y: actualY), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
let actionMoveDone = SKaction.removeFromParent()
monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actioinMove, actionMoveDone]))
```

}

In the code line

```
let actualY = random(min: monster.size.height/2, max: size.height - monster.size.height/2)
```

I'm getting an error of "Use of unresolved identifier 'size'"

Now, I'm guessing it's because there's no "identifier" like there is in the min: parameter (monster.size.height) vs. (size.height). What I don't know is, what that identifier needs to be. The error goes away only if I use SKScene.size.height but I don't think the tutorial owner is trying to set the maximum axis based on the scene minus the monster.

As I said, I am new. I have posted to the site forum for the tutorial owner to look at this. It could be a change in the revisions for Swift 2.2 (which I am still learning) so I may just be missing a new way to write the code.

This is my first question on stack overflow. In advance, it's nice to meet you all!

[edit: screenshot of specific line of code and error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFAVj.png)

Comment: Which size is giving the error?  `monster.size` or `size`?

Comment: The error comes from the max: area,    monster.size.height doesn't error but    size.height does.

Comment: What class is this code in?

Comment: root class is GameScene: SKScene{ However, It looks like it's separated into it's own function func addmonster() { ((I'm going to have to look up how to comment code in these comments, sorry about that.))

Comment: First of all you have a lot of typos... Fix that first. Your code compiles for me.

Comment: Also, this `size.height` when used inside of a `GameScene` class, or whatever your current scene is, is the same as `self.size.height`. The only difference is that in first example, an implicit self is used. But the effect is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like `size.height` inside of a `GameScene` class, or whatever your current scene is, is the same as `self.size.height`. The only difference between these two examples is usage of implicit self vs explicit self. But the effect is the same.

This error may happen if an instance doesn't have property called size. Both `SKScene`, and `SKSpriteNode` have it. This error may happen, for example, if monster was `SKNode` because `SKNode` doesn't have property called size.

So the above wasn't the issue and the real problem (as you have figured out already) was related to typos and to wrong code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are positioning the y position in relation to your SKScene position, try:

```
let actualY = random(min: monster.size.height/2, max: self.size.height - monster.size.height/2)
```

Edit: sorry I changed the wrong line of code, this is what I meant:

```
monster.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width + monster.size.width/2, y: actualY)
```

Comment: This : `self.size.width` is the same as `size.width` when used inside of a current scene class. Why do you think that there should be a difference ? This error may happen if an instance doesn't have property called `size`. Both `SKScene`, and `SKSpriteNode` have it. This error may happen if monster was `SKNode` because `SKNode` doesn't have property called `size`.

Comment: My thinking is that, while that is the case, it obviously isn't compiling as the SKScene's size property, so this may fix that problem.

Comment: @Whirlwind make your main comment (with code) into an answer. It helped me restructure my code within the SKScene and troubleshoot where I was going wrong. I ended up having to redo everything before I got it right, but with your advice I was able to build the app the correct way. It also taught me a lot! Thanks! BTW I'm emailing to join SKA, I've been looking everywhere for a place like that!